# Hyperledger Composer How to check hash code that is generated for transaction

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I am a blockchain learner. I took Hyperledger composer as the implementation for blockchain.

Developed a sample application using composer.

Now my question is

- how do I find the hashcode generated for the transaction? I can see only transaction ID's which are getting generated.
- How do I get a previous transaction or block information using current transaction?
- How to tell its a block chain based on the information stored?

I am not sure if this is the right question please correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install hyperledger-explorer along side. Check this [link here](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer)

Edit the explorer port in appConfig.json as explorer and playground will be using the same port (8080)

Comment: in addition to the above: this S/O answer will also guide you in regard to H/L Explorer config -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51020162/how-to-integrate-hyperledger-composer-business-network-with-hyperledger-explorer/51025119#51025119